# Where I can ask questions on filling and filing of (US) individual tax returns?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Some parts of the forms do not make sense. Is there a site for discussions on tax returns (Form 1040)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd try [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/), and tag your question either [income-tax-filing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-tax-filing) or [income-tax-returns](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/income-tax-returns) and include the jurisdiction (united-states, etc.).

Note that it's not a discussion site, but if you have a specific question, you'll probably get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't find it in the site list, but then I figured out it's still a beta.

Comment: Ah, yes, you need to look at the full Stack Exchange site list rather than the footer: http://stackexchange.com/sites#name

Comment: (cc @ysap) Personal Finance & Money has recently graduated, and can now be found in the footer under "Life / Arts".